# GPU Compute in Cycles Fails to Render When Using CUDA and GTX 1660 Ti

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

GPU Compute used to work fine but has only functioned for a few seconds at most in the current blender versions. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Nvidia Drivers have been updated to the latest available version.

Pictured below, the default cube appears to render without lighting when GPU Compute is selected.

[image: Here is my preferences panel in the latest release (Blender 2.83.2]

[image: The default cube appears to render without lighting when GPU Compute is selected]
[image]

Comment: Try using Optix

Comment: Both OptiX and OpenCL list the above compatibility issue.